# AndEngine multitouch extension

Tags: android, andengine

Simple question, do i need to include the multitouch extension in my project if i need to register presses on several sprites/onscreen controls at the same time? Im using andengine gles2

Answer (score 7):

No, in GLES2, the multi-touch is not a extension anymore, it is already integrated into AndEngine library itself.
So, you don't need to include it in your application project.
But, you need to configure your engine option to use multi-touch function. See this  [example](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/MultiTouchExample.java) code.